# How to fix the "Not allowed to load local resource" Vue.js

Tags: vue.js, resources, localhost, load

I tried to load some icons and logos into my site using localhost, files are detected but are not loaded and it says "Not allowed to load local resource", I also tried to run the app using "npm install -g http-server" in terminal, but I had another error: "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) @build.js:1"

Comment: How are you loading this file?

Comment: using
`<img src:"/*path*/">`

Comment: Just to be sure this is a typo, you meant to say you are using `<img src="/*path*/">` correct?

Comment: Well not exactly.
I have created some data as objects which include a text, link and a path and that's how i used them:
`<template>
<footer id="main-footer">
<div id="social-media">
<header>Join us on social media</header>
<ul>
<li v-for="el in elements" :key="el">
<a :href="el.href">
<img :src="el.src" :alt="el.alt">
</a>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
</footer>
</template>`


*elements is my data, an array including objects, including "src", "href" and "alt"

Comment: Ok that's good. If I remember correctly I believe you need to be using the public path if you are going to render images in a loop. Are you using images in the public path or in the assets folder?

Answer (score 1):

There are two common options for loading images.

Through the public folder. e.g. `<img src='/image/myImageName.png'>`

*Note: by specifying the root directory `/` vue is directed to the public folder*

Or through the assets folder. e.g. `<img src='@/assets/images/myImageName.png'>`

*Note: by supplying the `@` sign vue is directed to the src directory*

Comment: I have no problem directing the files, my problem is that my app cannot access the files, I have already mentioned the error message

Comment: @Kraken are you using the [vue cli](https://cli.vuejs.org/)? What happens if you use [yarn](https://yarnpkg.com/) e.g. `yarn serve`?

Comment: uh.. I don't know what is "yarn" but I will search about it